# How do I setup VPN connection between a Cisco router and kubernetes service

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, kubernetes

I have a kubernetes service exposed via a load balancer, works fine but I want access this service via a VPN service. 
The ip range of the service doesn't seem to match my VPC (does not know if that is a problem)

I have successfully setup a VPN tunnel between my VPC and the router.

Kindly, provide more info on what needs to be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing...

I exposed the service I was interested in via loadbalancer and then accessed it through the VPN via ***"privateNodeIp":"nodePort"***

[see the publishing services section of kubernetes guide](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/)